# perl tinyXML - node is not of type XmlNodePtr

Tags: xml, perl

Ive searched the docs on cpan and google, cant seem to find an answer.
Im using perl to read in an XML file.  When I do the following code it
complains that

XML::TinyXML::XmlGetChildNode: node is not of type XmlNodePtr at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/XML/TinyXML.pm line 485.

What do I have to do to my variable to make it an XmlNodePtr and use
it correctly to call getChildNode()?

`

```
my $xml = XML::TinyXML->new();
$xml->loadFile("myfile");

my $node = $xml->getRootNode(1);
my $val = $node->value("context");
print "root Node value: $val\n";    prints "root Node value: context"
my $clen = $node->countChildren();
print "total children $clen\n";     prints "total children 115"

my $this_node = $xml->getChildNode($node, 0);  <----error
```

`

Ive also tried what seems to be the proper solution (below)
from the XML::TinyXML::Node doc which also says:

XML::TinyXML::XmlGetChildNode: node is not of type XmlNodePtr at   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/XML/TinyXML.pm line 485.

`

```
my $ptr = XML::TinyXML::Node->new($node);
my $this_node = $xml->getChildNode($ptr, 0); <---- error
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `getChildNode` on `$node` itself. Also, node indices probably start at 1, not 0.

```
my $this_node = $node->getChildNode(1);
```

Comment: Thank you Michal, however I did try that with the same results.  I gave up and switched to XML::Simple instead, had it up and running in 15 minutes vs. the full day I lost trying to get TinyXML to work.